# How to add a column using the mapping vector after purrr::map_df

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm using the mtcars dataset as an example to illustrate my question.  I ran linear regression on each cylinder type and put all model result together using map_df. (Code and output below).  What I want to do is adding another column named 'cylinder' (4,4,6,6,8,8). How can I do that in map_df?  When I add argument .id='cylinder', I only got a column as 1,1,2,2,3,3.  Thanks a lot in advance.

```
library(purrr)
cyls <- c(4,6,8)
map_df(cyls, ~tidy(lm(hp~wt,data=mtcars %>% filter(cyl == .x))))
```

[image]

Comment: Are you open to alternatives to looping through a character vector?  I'd probably `split` the dataset into the cylinder groups instead, in which case `.id` would work: `split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl) %>% map_df(~tidy(lm(hp ~ wt, data = .)), .id = "cylinder")`

Comment: You could also set the names of `cyls` to use .`id` in `map_df` in your current work flow:  `cyls = set_names(cyls)`

Comment: @aosmith    Thanks. I'm not open to alternatives. I know how to do it this way.  But I need to figure out how to do that with map_df  in my real work.

Comment: @aosmith  yes. that will work. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `set_names` should do it

```
cyls %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map_df(., ~tidy(lm(hp~wt,data=mtcars %>% filter(cyl == .x))), .id = "cyls")

  cyls        term   estimate std.error   statistic
1    4 (Intercept)  69.204726  28.41355  2.43562436
2    4          wt   5.876308  12.09420  0.48587823
3    6 (Intercept) 187.273314  90.85245  2.06129062
4    6          wt -20.848451  28.98418 -0.71930440
5    8 (Intercept) 204.484626  78.77132  2.59592744
6    8          wt   1.182647  19.37501  0.06103983
     p.value
1 0.03763378
2 0.63866393
3 0.09427827
4 0.50415924
5 0.02340090
6 0.95233233
```