# Importing and Tidying from Terrible Excel Spreadsheet in R

Tags: r, regex, excel, dplyr, readxl

First, see [this url](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8gcy0j01hzjj5x/MyDataset.xlsx?dl=0) for a small example of the type of data I am formatting.  You'll note I have highlighted two areas in the worksheet that I am trying to select.  The selection range needs to be dynamic as projects move in and out of the datasets.  For the first part, I think this code will suffice:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

filename <- "MyDataset.xlsx"

#obtain first section of my excel spreadsheet
project_codes <- read_excel(
  path = filename,
  sheet = "Jan18",
  range = "A10:B1000",
  col_names = c("proj_num", "name")
) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  filter(grepl("-", project_codes$proj_num))
```

The second section is where I am getting tripped up...  I want to ensure that I have selected the exact same subset of rows as my 'project_codes' in the other highlighted area of the spreadsheet.

I have many worksheets formatted in this exact same way (and naming convention is consistent - Jan18, Feb18, Mar18), so bonus points if someone can assist me in iterating through the worksheets after solving part 1.

Comment: Asuming that we captured from row 6 downwards, are all the values you want to capture in every sheet under the titles: "#", "PROJECT NAME", "Status", "Cumulative Billings", "Billing Adjustment", "Contract Value"?

Comment: Yes - and all in same column location - and I could just rename the columns if I needed to

Comment: Your last line doesn't work as is. I'd change it to `filter(str_detect(proj_num, "-"))`.

Comment: Why not just grab everything from column A to N, and then use `select()` to remove the columns you don't need?

Comment: Assume there are 100 columns of 'noise' - I just can't help but believe there is a more efficient answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

filename <- "MyDataset.xlsx"

excel_sheets(filename) %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map_df(~ read_excel(
  path = filename,
  sheet = .,
  range = "A6:N1000"
) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(`#`, "-")) %>% 
  select(`#`, `PROJECT NAME`, `Status`, `Cumulative Billings`, `Billing Adjustment`, `Contract Value`), .id = "Month")

# A tibble: 8 x 7
  Month `#`       `PROJECT NAME` Status `Cumulative Billings` `Billing Adjustment` `Contract Value`
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>                 <dbl>                <dbl>            <dbl>
1 Jan18 1-11-0010 Project 1         715                  6723                 2138             1977
2 Jan18 1-11-0011 Project 2        1717                  8330                 8283             2588
3 Jan18 1-11-0012 Project 3        3332                  2908                 4938             7734
4 Jan18 1-11-0013 Project 4        2589                  8714                 6034             1476
5 Jan18 1-11-0014 Project 5         588                  4969                 2161             3334
6 Jan18 1-11-0015 Project 6         820                  7688                 4243             4293
7 Jan18 1-11-0020 Project 20       7287                   333                 9100             3078
8 Jan18 1-11-0030 Project 30       1564                   487                 7249             5508
```

`map_df()` will iterate through each sheet (whose names are extracted using `excel_sheets()`) and create one data frame with a column indicating which sheet the data comes from.

I had to rely on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189979/how-to-add-a-column-using-the-mapping-vector-after-purrrmap-df) to apply the name of the sheet as its own column.